# Que signifie « l' » dans la locution verbale « L'emporter (sur) » ?

Tags: étymologie

> [ [TLF :](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/emporter) ] Loc. verbale. *L'emporter (sur)*. Avoir la supériorité, le dessus lorsqu'on est en lutte, en compétition, en concurrence.

Le « l' » : est-il un pronom explétif ou pléonastique ? Ou jadis a-t-il eu un antécédent qui n'est plus conservé ou bien connu ?

Answer (score 2):

L'antécédent implicite désigne ce qui est (r)emporté en surpassant son adversaire : la victoire, la compétition, le combat, la course, le duel, le marché, la partie, le prix, la coupe, etc.